# How can I improve "SNR" in a measurement of noise power?

Tags: noise, microwave, signal-to-noise

I'm doing an experiment where I need to use a shot-noise tunnel junction as a calibrated noise source to characterize our measurement system. This is done by sweeping the voltage across the SNTJ and measuring the output noise power on a spectrum analyzer. What I'm finding is that from measurement to measurement, there's a substantial amount of variation in the measured noise power. I want to try to improve the SNR of my setup (S in this case being noise power rather than a typical signal). Is there anything I can do besides increasing the averaging time? For example, adding or removing amplifiers from my signal chain.